# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'url'

Tags: python, web-services, cherrypy

I am trying to run [dripls](https://github.com/hulu/dripls) and when I install everything including fabric, apache2 and setup appropriate configuration files

I have the following problem

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'url'
```

its from the package [cherrypy](http://www.cherrypy.org)

On this line

```
app = {
  'root_url': cherrypy.url()
}
```

Could anyone point out what might be the problem?

**Update: **

Problematic script (full)

```
import cherrypy
import urlparse
import uuid
import os

    # Service
socket = '0.0.0.0'
dripls_main_site_port = 8080
thread_pool = 10

bin_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))), "bin")
pidfile = os.path.join(bin_path, "dripls.pid")
error_log = os.path.join(bin_path, "error_log.log")
access_log = os.path.join(bin_path, "access_log.log")

app = {
  'root_url': cherrypy.url()
}

# Shaper path
shaper_path = os.path.join(bin_path, "set_ts_lo.sh")

# Shape port range 
shape_start_port = 10000
shape_end_port = 11000

# Environment overrides
if os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "env.py")):
    from env import *
else:
    from local import *

port = int(dripls_main_site_port)

# Final url rewrite. Hack to battle the fact that cherrypy is behind a proxy on different port  
def get_final_url(path, args):
    cherrypy_url = cherrypy.url(path, args)

    scheme, netloc, path, qs, anchor = urlparse.urlsplit(cherrypy_url)
    return urlparse.urlunsplit( (scheme, urlparse.urlsplit(app['root_url'])[1], path, qs, anchor))

def get_seeded_cid(cid):
    return "{0}_{1}".format(cid, uuid.uuid4().hex)"
```

**Update :**

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 05:46:21) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cherrypy 
>>> cherrypy.url
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'url'
>>> print cherrypy.__file__
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cherrypy/__init__.pyc
>>>
```

Comment: please share the full code or function.

Comment: Right after you import cherrypy, print cherrypy.__file__ to make sure you are importing the right thing.

Comment: i am porting the right file i think :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but I found out the problem.

It did not work if you install cherrypy using

```
sudo apt-get install python-cherrypy
```

You have install pip using

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

and then

```
sudo pip install CherryPy
```

Comment: It was a version problem. What was the versions? `apt-cache show python-cherrypy` / `pip freeze | grep -i cherry`

Answer (score 1):

That should work:

```
>>> import cherrypy
>>> cherrypy.url
<function url at 0xb6d8f80c>
```

Make sure that you didn't named the script `cherrypy.py`. If you did, it will prevent importing of `cherrypy` package.

Rename the file, and make sure there's no `cherrypy.pyc` file remained.

Comment: It is named properly I think. You can check the console out above :(